# regular expression to select records that meet numerical conditions

Tags: regex, grep

I need to implement a regular expression that given the following sample dataset, allows me to select those student records that were born in a month of January and prior to the year 2000, and whose course grade is higher than 1.7. For example, the result of the command in the following sample should be the second record

```
id, date of birth, grade, explusion, serious misdemeanor
123,2005-01-01,5.36,1,1
582,1999-10-12,8.51,0,1
9274,2001-25-12,9.65,0,0
```

I've tried the following but I get no results after executing

```
grep -E "^*,1[0-9]{3}(-[0-9]{2}){2}*[10],(1\.[7-9][1-9])]"
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: The one thing which is wrong, is the usage of `grep` for numerical conditions: `grep`, or regular expressions in general, are used for text-based conditions, not numerical ones. For numerical ones, other tools like `awk` are far better suited.

Comment: Hi @Dominique I need to use grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep, you might write the full pattern as

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+,1[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-0?1,(1\.(7[1-9][0-9]*|[89][0-9]*)|[2-9](\.[0-9]+)?|10(\.0+)?),[0-9]+,[0-9]+$' file
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]+,` Match 1+ digits and `,` for the id
- `1[0-9]{3}-` Match 1, 3 digits and `-` for the year
- `[0-9]{2}-0?1,` Match 2 digits `-` and either 01 or 1 for the January
- `(` Group for the alternatives

  - `1\.(7[1-9][0-9]*|[89][0-9]*)` Match 1.71-1.79 or 1.8 or 1.9 all followed by optional digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[2-9](\.[0-9]+)?` Match 2-9 optionally followed by `.` and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `10(\.0+)?` Match 10 optionally followed by `.` and zeroes (assuming 10 is the highest grade)
- `),` Close the group and match a comma
- `[0-9]+,[0-9]+` Match the last 2 column values, assuming 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3tGGo9/1) and a [bash demo](https://tio.run/##dVDRasMwDHzvV4gyaLLJRnLmOn7q074i3SBd3MWwNiVuYbD02zMn2Z6SGcOd7qST8aEMdd@797qBta8QqvLqoDnCwbfXGuGjLSuH4L4un7fgmzNCcK1vbgFOPlTu5Mpz065YZaiItCCOF7XMtsjIK50rZGutYBKsMJeakeY600yNKSzNcrfMaTxzE9XygJl6rTLPwztZKD0YVm51NGhhQP6z2gzyGrr4Me4C4gU2bwUJ@/qEPOJ3dhcTUXdBO8aE9zIxBUdp1B@7Iv@jaVeoiMleThnprmOKFUWW4m/uBA@bvv8B).

Comment: and If I just want to select those who were born in January?

Comment: @fortnite Ow yes, in January like this https://regex101.com/r/u1IvA9/1

Comment: @fortnite Do you also want to allow partial matches in other structured lines and should the grade always have to dot?

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct, but I don't understand why I don't get the January values.

Comment: @fortnite See this [bash demo](https://tio.run/##dVDRasMwDHzvV4gyaLLJRnLmOn7q074i3SBd3MWwNiVuYbD02zMn2Z6SGcOd7qST8aEMdd@797qBta8QqvLqoDnCwbfXGuGjLSuH4L4un7fgmzNCcK1vbgFOPlTu5Mpz065YZaiItCCOF7XMtsjIK50rZGutYBKsMJeakeY600yNKSzNcrfMaTxzE9XygJl6rTLPwztZKD0YVm51NGhhQP6z2gzyGrr4Me4C4gU2bwUJ@/qEPOJ3dhcTUXdBO8aE9zIxBUdp1B@7Iv@jaVeoiMleThnprmOKFUWW4m/uBA@bvv8B)

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, I can't find the january part and the grade doesn't look correct. Here's a simpler one:

```
grep -E '1...-..-01,([2-9]\.)|(1\.[7-9][1-9])'
```

Explanation:

```
1...-..-01     year=1xxx, month=01
[2-9]\.|       grade 2-9 or
1.[7-9][1-9]   grade 1.7[1-9]
```

Assumes `grade < 10` (can be changed easily).

awk is a bit more straightforward:

```
awk -F[,-] '$2<2000 && $4=="01" && $5 > 1.7'
```

Comment: Hi @steffen your solution correctly chooses those whose score is higher than 1.7, also those who were born before 2000 but it doesn't get the year correctly.

Comment: Sorry I mean the month

Comment: @fortnite I swapped day and month to match `YYYY-DD-MM`.

Comment: Sorry. You are absolutely right. You got what you deserved. I've validated your answer